# Date and time in different languages

Tags: android, date, time, format

I want my app to show the German version if the phone language is German, and the English version if the phone language is English.

There is this `Predefined Formats`, but for the German version I don't like it.

How can I handle this?

```
private fun getTime(currentTime:Long): String{
    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = currentTime
    val str = sdf.format(calendar.time)
    return str
}

private fun getDate(currentTime:Long):String{
    val myDate = Date()
    val actualDate = myDate.time.plus(currentTime)
    val myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(actualDate)
    return myString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this constructor:

```
public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)
```

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat())